# Two scrolling blocks in flex container

Tags: css, flexbox, vertical-scrolling

I need to build a card with two scrolling areas. Initial idea was to use flexbox so I came up with this:

```css
.card {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 0;
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 80%;
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.photo {
  background-color: silver;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  aspect-ratio: 3;
}

.body {
  display: flex;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.title {
  background-color: silver;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.text {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: cyan;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.photos {
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.photos * ~ * {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.thumbnail {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  aspect-ratio: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="photo">Photo</div>
  
  <div class="body">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="title">Title</div>
      <div class="text" contenteditable>
        Full text<br>
        Can be multiline and with vertical scroll
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="photos">
      <div class="thumbnail">Thumbnail</div>
      <div class="thumbnail">Thumbnail</div>
      <div class="thumbnail">Thumbnail</div>
      <div class="thumbnail">Thumbnail</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

link to fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/SkyLight/jxobz8qn/

The card has maximum width and height and `Full text` section (cyan one) can have pretty long content so that it should have scroll when needed. `Thumbnails` section can also have big amount of items so will also need to have scroll.

I know that `overflow` needs block to have `height` set in order to work but I can't figure out how to set it properly because the content should be limited mainly by `Card`'s max size.

So can it be achieved with flexbox only or I'll need some other stuff? Would like to achieve the result with pure css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the card element a flexbox container then use `flex:1` on the body:

```css
.card {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 0;
  max-width: 80%;
  max-height: 80%;
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 10px;
  /* added */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /**/
}

.photo {
  background-color: silver;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  aspect-ratio: 3;
}

.body {
  display: flex;
  flex:1; /* added */
  min-height:0;  /* added to make sure the content will shrink */
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.title {
  background-color: silver;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.text {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: cyan;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.photos {
  width: 100px;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.photos * ~ * {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.thumbnail {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  aspect-ratio: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="photo">Photo</div>
  
  <div class="body">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="title">Title</div>
      <div class="text" contenteditable>
        Full text<br>
        Can be multiline and with vertical scroll
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="photos">
      <div class="thumbnail">Thumbnail</div>
      <div class="thumbnail">Thumbnail</div>
      <div class="thumbnail">Thumbnail</div>
      <div class="thumbnail">Thumbnail</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A small thing I was missing... Thanks, it finally works as expected